# Kotlin call java method with Class<T> argument

Tags: java, kotlin

I want to use Spring `RestTemplate` in Kotlin like this:

```
//import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate
fun findAllUsers(): List<User> {
        val restTemplate = RestTemplate()

        //has error
        val ret = List<User>.javaClass
        return restTemplate.getForObject(URI(hostAddress), ret)
}
```

The `RestTemplate.getForObject(URI url, Class<T> responseType)` has this signature and I get this error "unresolved reference List" from `List` in `val ret = List<User>.javaClass`.

If I use like this `val ret = List<User>::class.java` I get this error "Only classes are allowed on the left hand side of a class literal"

what's the problem? and what's the proper way for doing this? Is it a bug?

Comment: I think that `val ret = List<User>` is enough. You don't nned to 'cast' it. Check: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/collections.html

Comment: @piotrek1543  no It has "unresolved reference List" error.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36915823

Answer (score 54, accepted):

@edwin's answer is correct, you had an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) where you were actually asking for the wrong thing.  Thankfully you had an error in doing so which led you here and @edwin was able to explain the alternative which does the correct behavior.

Every binding library for Java has some pattern like this that is the same (`Class` vs. type reference). So this is good thing to learn and look for in your library such as RestTemplate, Jackson, GSON and others.  The utility class maybe is `ParameterizedTypeReference` in one, and `TypeReference` in another, `TypeRef` in yet another and so on; but all doing the same thing.

**Now, for anyone wondering what was wrong with the original code**, to create an generics erased class reference such as `Class<T>` the syntax would be:

```kotlin
val ref = List::class.java
```

You will notice there is no way to express the generic type of the items in the list.  And even if you could, they would be erased anyway due to type erasure.  Passing this to the binding library would be like saying "*a list of maybe nullable java.lang.Object please*" but worse.   Imagine `Map<String, List<Int>>` where you now lost all information that would make deserializing this possible.

The following **does not** compile:

```kotlin
val ref = List<String>::class.java  // <--- error only classes are allowed on left side
```

The error message could be clearer to say "*only classes without generic parameters are allowed on the left side of ::*"

And your use of `javaClass` can only be used on an instance, so if you happen to have had a list handy...

```kotlin
val ref = listOf("one", "two", "three").javaClass
```

Then you would end up with a type erased `Class<T>` which again is the wrong thing to use here, but valid syntax.

**So what does the code @edwin is showing actually do?**

By creating an object with a super type `ParameterizedTypeReference` the code works around this problem because any class, even if type erased, can see the generics in its superclass and interfaces via the lense of `Type`.  For example:

```kotlin
val xyz = object : MySuperClass<SomeGenerics>() {}
```

This instance of an anonymous class has the superclass `MySuperClass` with generic parameters of `SomeGenerics`.  So if `MySuperClass` contained this code:

```kotlin
abstract class MySuperClass<T> protected constructor() {
    val type: Type = (javaClass.genericSuperclass as ParameterizedType)
                                 .actualTypeArguments[0]
}
```

You could then add  `.type` to the end of our declaration to access this functionality:

```kotlin
val typeOfSomeGenerics = object : MySuperClass<SomeGenerics>() {}.type
```

And now you would have some implementation of `Type` describing our `SomeGenerics` class.  It would be one of:  `Class`, `ParameterizedType`, `GenericArrayType`, `TypeVariable`, and `WildcardType`

And by understanding and working with these, a library that does data binding knows enough to do its job.

**Life is easier in Kotlin:**

In Kotlin, it is easy to write extension functions so that you never have to do this type of code more than once.  Just create a helper inline function that uses reified generics to pass through the type and create the `ParameterizedTypeReference`:

```kotlin
inline fun <reified T: Any> typeRef(): ParameterizedTypeReference<T> = object: ParameterizedTypeReference<T>(){}
```

And now you can change @edwin's example to:

```kotlin
val response = restTemplate.exchange(request, typeRef<List<String>>())
```

Comment: In short. Create a class `open class ParameterizedTypeReference<T>`.  And call the function like this:  `myFunc((object: ParameterizedTypeReference<List<Long>>(){}.javaClass.genericSuperclass as ParameterizedType).actualTypeArguments[0])`

Answer (score 20):

You may try

```
return restTemplate.getForObject(URI(hostAddress), Array<User>::class.java).toList()
```

Comment: This is the most elegant and fluent solution for this problem.

Answer (score 15):

I think you need to actually use the `RestTemplate.exechange` method that has a signature that accepts a `ParameterizedTypeReference<T>` where `T` can be the generic type of your response (in your case a `List<User>`)

Suppose I have an endpoint that returns a list of Jedi names in JSON format, as follows

```
["Obi-wan","Luke","Anakin"]
```

And I would like to invoke this endpoint and get a `List<String>` as the result, with the list containing the Jedi names from the JSON.

Then I can do this:

```
val endpoint = URI.create("http://127.0.0.1:8888/jedi.json")
val request = RequestEntity<Any>(HttpMethod.GET, endpoint)
val respType = object: ParameterizedTypeReference<List<String>>(){}
val response = restTemplate.exchange(request, respType)
val items: List<String> = response.body;
println(items) //prints [Obi-wan, Luke, Anakin]
```

Notice that my `ParameterizedTypeReference` has a type argument of `List<String>`. That's what does the trick.

And that worked for me when I tried it.

Comment: The `RestTemplate.getForObject` expects a `Class<T>` as parameter to identify the type of your response, but a class is not enough to explain what you want. For example, you expect to get `List.class` as response, but it does not tell of which type argument that list is (e.g. `List<User>`). So, you need a different method signature that uses `ParameterizedTypeReference` to tell both things, the type of the resulting class and its type arguments.

Answer (score -1):

First, you will make a new class - UserList.kt (the name is our owner)

Inside:

```
class UserList : MutableList<User> by ArrayList()
```

After that, you can call your method that has a `RestTemplate`

```
val response: List < Item > ? = restTemplate.getObject("yourEndpoint", UserList::class.java)
```

It may be returns `null`, so you need to take care of that.