# How to `List<MyClass>::clas.java` in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, mockito

I want to use `ArgumentCaptor` in `kotlin`.

What I've done :

```
val c := ArgumentCaptor<List<MyClass>, 
List<MyClass>>.forClass(List<MyClass>::class.java)
```

but it says

`Only classes are allowed on the left hand side of a class literal`

Comment: syntax error, change `:=` to `='

Comment: "Type Erasure". Take a look at this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39679180/kotlin-call-java-method-with-classt-argument) for a very good explanation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```java
ArgumentCaptor<List<MyClass>> c = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(List<MyClass>.class);
```

doesn't compile in Java either, because at runtime `<MyClass>` isn't part of the type due to erasure.

Instead, consider using [`com.nhaarman:mockito-kotlin`](https://github.com/nhaarman/mockito-kotlin) which wraps Mockito with an API more suitable for use from Kotlin.

```kotlin
val c = argumentCaptor<List<MyClass>>()
```