# How do I make sure I am returning a List of specified type?

Tags: java, httpresponse

I would like to return a list of `ListItem`s with this function, but when it is set up this way I get an unchecked assignment warning, because the returned list isnt specified to contain `ListItem`s. This causes the build to fail.

- Tried casting in the return statement but then I get an unchecked cast warning
- Tried specifying the list type when declaring the `responseEntity`, but then I have to also specify the response type parameter (`List.class` -> `List<ListItem>.class`), which fails because it cannot select from a parameterized type

```
private static final String GET_LIST_ITEMS= "/listItemsEndpoint";

private final RestTemplate myRestTemplate;

//constructor

public List<ListItem> getListItems() {
   
    headers.add("id", "abc");

    HttpEntity<String> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<>(headers);

    ResponseEntity<List> responseEntity =
        myRestTemplate.exchange(GET_LIST_ITEMS, HttpMethod.GET, httpEntity, List.class);


    return responseEntity.getBody();
}
```

Comment: Use _new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<ListItem>>() {}_ instead of _List.class_ see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36915823/spring-resttemplate-and-generic-types-parameterizedtypereference-collections-lik

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use `ParameterizedTypeReference`. If you are *always* returning a `List<ListItem>`, then you can make it a constant (no need to keep re-instantiating it!):

```
private static final ParameterizedTypeReference<List<ListItem>> LIST_OF_ITEM =
    new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<ListItem>>() {};
```

Then, in your exchange, use `LIST_OF_ITEM` instead of the class literal `List.class`.