# deserilization error using resttemplate

Tags: java, json, rest, deserialization

I have pinpointed where the issue is happening but having hard time resolving it .

My Json Response is such

```
{
{...},
{...},
{...}

}
```

This is my current code to retrieve the response.

```
ResponseEntity<Object[]> responseEntity  = restTemplate.getForEntity("http://api.walmartlabs.com/v1/nbp?apiKey={apiKey}&itemId={itemID}", Object[].class,WalmartAPIKey.APIKey,productId);
ProductRecommendations[] pra = (ProductRecommendations[]) responseEntity.getBody();
```

I can also see the array in `responseEntity.getBody()` but the issue is I am unable to map it to a POJO gives me type casting error.

Is there a way to get around it or do it a better way?

Comment: What you have there doesn't look like valid JSON. An object must have keys and values, not just values. I guess what you get is in fact an array. Also, what would you do with an array of objects. You probably want something much more specific, like a List<Product>. Read http://stackoverflow.com/a/31947188/571407

Comment: I am on same post as the one you mentioned. 
When I try doing a Array of Products on responseEntity.getBody() I get class cast exception

Comment: I linked specifically to the second answer, which doesn use arrays at all. Use a List<Product>, and a new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<Produc>>, as shown in the specific response I linked to.