# How do I get a list of JSON objects out of an array among other objects using Spring RestTemplate?

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson, resttemplate

I'm trying to consume this data

> https://api.nasa.gov/neo/rest/v1/neo/browse?api_key=DEMO_KEY

following the tutorial from

> http://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest/

I successfully retrieve the "links" and "page" portions of the data, but the array of near_earth_objects is null.

I tried what was suggested in this post:

> [Get list of JSON objects with Spring RestTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23674046/get-list-of-json-objects-with-spring-resttemplate)

But my situation is a little more complicated because it's more than just one array filled with objects as seen in

> http://bitpay.com/api/rates

Top answer gives error:

```
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not 
deserialize instance of java.lang.Object[] out of START_OBJECT token
```

Here is what my POJO looks like:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class NearEarthObjectBrowse {
    @Id
    private Links links;
    private Page page;
    private NearEarthObject[] near_earth_objects;
```

I also tried using a wrapper class for the `NearEarthObject` array and still was unable to marshal successfully.

Is there a better way to go about doing this in general?

**Edit**: I believe the structure of NearEarthObject matches the data. Here is my [github](https://github.com/jleczner/AsteroidDeath/blob/working/AsteroidsAreDopeServer/src/main/java/leczner/jon/AsteroidsAreDopeServer/model/NearEarthObjectBrowse.java)

Comment: can you also post NearEarthObject class?

Comment: you have given multiple links for different json, which one you are consuming in your code ?

Comment: Post a complete, minimal example reproducing the problem.

Comment: @Jobin I've added the link to the code in my github.

Comment: @DerrickDaniel 

"I'm trying to consume this data

https://api.nasa.gov/neo/rest/v1/neo/browse?api_key=DEMO_KEY"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use A list instead of an array for near_earth_objects

```
@JsonProperty("near_earth_objects")
private List<NearEarthObject> near_earth_objects;
```

Comment: This was it, thanks! The @JsonProperty line makes it work as expected.