# Can restTemplate.getForObject("URL", Object[].class) return NULL?

Tags: java, spring, resttemplate

I have used the solution from this answer:
[Get list of JSON objects with Spring RestTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23674046/get-list-of-json-objects-with-spring-resttemplate/26796142#26796142)
It works perfectly. It doing exactly what I need.

```
ProcessDefinition[] response = restTemplate.getForObject(url, ProcessDefinition[].class);
```

Is it enought:

```
return Arrays.asList(response);
```

or will be better this way:

```
return Arrays.asList(Optional.ofNullable(response).orElse(new ProcessDefinition[0]));
```

P.S. Sorry for starting the new topic, but my karma does not allow me to comment the answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, the result of

```
ProcessDefinition[] response = restTemplate.getForObject(url, ProcessDefinition[].class);
```

can be `null` if HTTP response body was empty (not `[]`, but totally empty body).

So it is safer to check it if you are not sure that HTTP response never be empty.

```
return Optional.ofNullable(response).map(Arrays::asList).orElseGet(ArrayList::new)
```

or

```
return Optional.ofNullable(response).map(Stream::of).orElseGet(Stream::empty)
```

if you need a stream.