# Consume REST Service using Spring RestTemplate

Tags: java, spring, rest

I just want to consume this response using Spring based Rest Template.I have tried different solutions but didn't worked out.

```
{
    "response": {
        "Status": "200",
        "data": [{
            "VehicleNo": "TS 11UB 5548",
            "lat": "17.44289",
            "lng": "78.39668",
            "timestamp": "19-01-2018 15:16:49",
            "speed": "0"
        }, {
            "VehicleNo": "TS 34T 3298",
            "lat": "17.44278",
            "lng": "78.39675",
            "timestamp": "19-01-2018 15:16:41",
            "speed": "0"
        }]
    }
}
```

Below is my Code which I have tried

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        Response response = restTemplate.getForObject("URL:XXXXXXXX", Response.class);
```

Response is the class which contains ("GPSEnabledVehicles" - data)

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Response {

    private GPSEnabledVehicles response;

    public GPSEnabledVehicles getResponse() {
        return response;
    }

    public void setResponse(GPSEnabledVehicles response) {
        this.response = response;
    }
}
```

Below is the GPSEnabledVehicles class which has status and List of VehicleDetails as attributes

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class GPSEnabledVehicles {

    private String status;
    private List<VehicleDetails> vehicleDetails;

//Setters and Getter
}
```

Please help me on this ASAP.Thanks in Advance.

Comment: So what did you try? Show us the code!

Comment: I have edited please check @C-Otto

Comment: Your code looks fine. what is the exception you are getting with this code? May be you need to pass headers/token for authentication.

Comment: The field containing the list of vehicles in the JSON is named `data`. Not `vehicleDetails`. And, BTW, the status field is named `Status`, not `status`.

Comment: Check out this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23674046/get-list-of-json-objects-with-spring-resttemplate

Comment: will work on it and let you know.Thanks @JBNizet, swaroop

Comment: @JBNizet , Changed vehicleDetails to data and status to Status . It is working fine , able to consume all the details but the VehicleNo and Status are returning nulls

Comment: This is the response getting         "[response=GPSEnabledVehicles [Status=null, data=[VehicleDetails [VehicleNo=null, lat=17.4908, lng=78.4072, timestamp=19-01-2018 17:32:42, speed=0], VehicleDetails [VehicleNo=null, lat=17.44285, lng=78.39652, timestamp=19-01-2018 17:31:34, speed=0]]"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class GPSEnabledVehicles {

    private String status;
    @JsonProperty("data")   ===> this
    private List<VehicleDetails> vehicleDetails;

//Setters and Getter
}
```

or

```
public class GPSEnabledVehicles {

    private String status;
    private List<VehicleDetails> data;   ==> same name

//Setters and Getter
}
```

[JsonProperty](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.3.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonProperty.html)

Comment: It's working but, the VehicleNo and Status are returning nulls. Here is the response  ----->   "[response=GPSEnabledVehicles [Status=null, data=[VehicleDetails [VehicleNo=null, lat=17.4908, lng=78.4072, timestamp=19-01-2018 17:32:42, speed=0], VehicleDetails [VehicleNo=null, lat=17.44285, lng=78.39652, timestamp=19-01-2018 17:31:34, speed=0]]"

Comment: Check status == Status similarly check VehicalNo, Or add this VehicleDetails class for me to check