# Wrap list to object with jackson annotations

Tags: java, spring, jackson, deserialization, jackson-databind

I receive a json list of objects. Let's call it list of some class `MyClass.class`. So I can easy deserialize it to `List<MyClass>`. But I want to add a wrapper class, for example:

```
class MyWrapper {

    private List<MyClass> items;

    //Getter & Setter

}
```

And I want to deserialize the following json:

```
[
    {
        ...
    },
    {
        ...
    }
]
```

to `MyWrapper.class`. How can I do it using jackson annotations ?

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23674046/get-list-of-json-objects-with-spring-resttemplate

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get list of JSON objects with Spring RestTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23674046/get-list-of-json-objects-with-spring-resttemplate)

Comment: How hard would it be to do new MyWrapper(items)?

Answer (score 0):

your wrapper class will be serialized to something like this.

```
{
   "items":[
       {...},
       {...}
    ]
}
```

which is not same as your input. If you can access JSON object before serialization, you can modify input.

```
String modifiedJson = "{\"items\":" + input + "}";
```