# Why does RestTemplate getForEntity returns an Array of objects instead of a List?

Tags: spring-boot, resttemplate

We were discussing with the colleagues as to why the call below returns an array in the ResponseEntity:

```
    ResponseEntity<WakeupProviderSettingsDTO[]> rep = 
restTemplate.getForEntity(url, WakeupProviderSettingsDTO[].class);
```

instead of a `List<WakeupProviderSettingsDTO>` or sth.

Why can't we simply transfer entities as lists?

Is it because [There are no Class literals for parameterized types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390662/java-how-do-i-get-a-class-literal-from-a-generic-type)?

Is it a performance thing? is it because of the fixed size of response set?

Comment: you're specifying the return type as an array in your call: restTemplate.getForEntity(url, WakeupProviderSettingsDTO[].class); so that's what the restTemplate is expecting. I guess this one helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23674046/get-list-of-json-objects-with-spring-resttemplate

Answer (score 1):

As you have pointed out in that post.

> You can not use .class token with parameterized types

This is one of those rare scenarios where you would use generic type List. So you could do like this

```
ResponseEntity<List> rep = restTemplate.getForEntity(url, List.class);
```

But with this you ofcourse lose the advantages that you would get with parameterized types.

If you wish to use List with parameterized types, You can still do it using `ParameterizedTypeReference`.

To answer your question, this has nothing to do with performance or fixet size response, this is a limitation of java Generics.