# Java Spring JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance out of START_ARRAY token

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, jackson

I have a method with a restTemplate call like this:

```
restTemplate.getForObject(apiUrl ,Someclass.class);
```

Someclass.class:

```
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Imp implements Serializable {
    @JsonProperty("Id")
    private String Id;

    @JsonProperty("ReportId")
    private String ReportId;

    @JsonProperty("Title")
    private String Title;

    @JsonProperty("Name")
    private String Name;

    @JsonProperty("Uri")
    private String Uri;

}
```

The API returns an array, and the **error** i'm receiving is:
*org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Error while extracting response for type [class ...] and content type [application/json;charset=utf-8]; nested exception is org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of `com...` out of START_ARRAY token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `com...` out of START_ARRAY token*

Which restTempalte method shoud i use to get proper api response?, or where is the problem?.thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You said the API returns an array.

But your line of code `restTemplate.getForObject(apiUrl ,Someclass.class);`
will work only for a single Someclass object.

You should use new `ParameterizedTypeReference<List<Someclass.class>>` along with the exchange method.

Refer to the below link

[Get list of JSON objects with Spring RestTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23674046/get-list-of-json-objects-with-spring-resttemplate)

Comment: ParameterizedTypeReference is not being recognized by the IDE.

Comment: Check the doc https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/ParameterizedTypeReference.html. Maybe the import statements are missing

Comment: ok i had to import it manually, can you tell what the method should be?, if i do this:
restTemplate.getForObject(apiUrl , ParameterizedTypeReference<List<Someclass.class>>);
An expression is expected, pointed by the IDE...

Comment: i could resolve it by following: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23674046/get-list-of-json-objects-with-spring-resttemplate  yonia's answer