# How to read below json string that is returned be resttemplate.exchange

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, resttemplate

How to read each from value below array that is returned by resttemplate.exchange

```
[
{
Name:Johny
Age:20
Id:300
Dod:shbk
Rank:50
},
{
Name:Johny
Age:20
Id:300
Dod:shbk
Rank:50
},
{
Name:Johny
Age:20
Id:300
Dod:shbk
Rank:50
},
{
Name:Johny
Age:20
Id:300
Dod:shbk
Rank:50
}

]
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/23674046/6572971 might help you.

Comment: Thank you , but in instead of usingParameterizedTypeReference<List<BitPay>>(){}) i used String.class so in i got response as a string then i need to read each value from string. Any idea that could be the helpfull