# Reading a list in another object from a restTemplate response

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have gone through some of the questions here and their answers like this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23674046/get-list-of-json-objects-with-spring-resttemplate?rq=1) which tells us how to extract a list of objects from a restTemplate response. It does not, however, solve my problem which is, I have an Entry class

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Entry {


    private String API;
    private String Description;
    private String Auth;
    private boolean HTTPS;
    private String Cors;
    private String Link;
    private String Category;
//    getters and setters
}
```

then I have an Entry implementation class which has

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class EntryImpl {
    private Long count;
    private ArrayList<Entry> entries;


    public EntryImpl () {

    }
//  getters and setters
}
```

and here is my request implementation to consume this [api](https://api.publicapis.org/entries)

```
public class RestConsump {
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        String url = "https://api.publicapis.org/entries";
        EntryImpl entries = restTemplate.getForObject(url, EntryImpl.class);
        System.out.println(entries.getEntries().get(0)); // returns null for all entries 
        System.out.println(entries.getCount()); // prints the numbers of entries
    }
}
```

My question is, how do I implement it so that EntryImpl returns the list of entries and the count.

Answer (score 0):

I executed the code above and got this response:

```
{API=AdoptAPet, Description=Resource to help get pets adopted, Auth=apiKey, HTTPS=true, Cors=yes, Link=https://www.adoptapet.com/public/apis/pet_list.html, Category=Animals}
1417
```

I used spring-web:5.3.8 for the RestTemplate, java version 15. Perhaps you are using an outdated RestTemplate?